# Is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra the largest one where $\mu^\star$ is $\sigma$-additive?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu^\star$ the usual outer measure. If we restrict $\mu^\star$ to $\Lambda$, then $\mu^\star$ is $\sigma$-additive and we also know that $\mu^\star$ is not $\sigma$-additive in the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

My questions are the following:

> 1) Take any non-measurable set $S$. Consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by the collection $\Lambda\cup \{S\}$. Is $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

If the answer for the question 1 is negative:

> 2) Can we conclude that $\mu^\star$ is not $\sigma$-additive in $\mathcal{A}$?

My thoughts on this problem: in a way, I want to know if the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is the largest one where $\mu^\star$ is $\sigma$-additive. I was trying to consider the collection $\mathcal{C}$ of all sets $E\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{E})$ such that if $E$ can be written as a disjoint union $E=\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$, then $$\mu^\star(E)=\sum _{i=1}^\infty \mu^\star (E_i).$$

I was trying to prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{C}=\Lambda$, however, the calculations were getting too big. Any idea or reference is appreciated.